# Do windows forms have fewer permissions than console applications?

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi, pinvoke

I have created a library to inject DLL files into processes using a variety of methods. I am testing it out with a GUI using Windows Forms.

All the methods work as intended except when using QueueUserAPC. When I attempt to use this method, the process that I am injecting a DLL into crashes.

I created a basic console application to test this method outside of a Windows Form and it worked as intended without the process crashing. Furthermore, my error checking tells me that the DLL is injecting without any errors when using the QueueUserAPC method from a Windows Form, however, the process still crashes.

I have a feeling that the reason the process is crashing when using a Windows Form isn't to do with the code of the QueueUserAPC method and more about the permissions of a Windows Form. However, I could be wrong so I will include the code for the method below.

**pinvoke**

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern IntPtr OpenProcess(ProcessPrivileges dwDesiredAccess, bool bInheritHandle, int dwProcessId);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern IntPtr GetProcAddress(IntPtr hModule, string procName);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern IntPtr VirtualAllocEx(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpAddress, uint dwSize, MemoryAllocation flAllocationType, MemoryProtection flProtect);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool WriteProcessMemory(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpBaseAddress, byte[] lpBuffer, uint nSize, int lpNumberOfBytesWritten);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool QueueUserAPC(IntPtr pfnAPC, IntPtr hThread, IntPtr dwData);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern void CloseHandle(IntPtr handle);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
public static extern void VirtualFreeEx(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpAddress, int dwSize, MemoryAllocation dwFreeType);

public enum MemoryAllocation
{
    Commit = 0x1000,
    Reserve = 0x2000,
    Release = 0x8000,
    AllAccess = Commit | Reserve
}

public enum MemoryProtection
{
    PageReadWrite = 0x04,
    PageExecuteReadWrite = 0x40
}

public enum ThreadAccess
{
    SuspendResume = 0x02,
    GetContext = 0x08,
    SetContext = 0x010,
    AllAccess = SuspendResume | GetContext | SetContext
}
```

**QueueUserAPC Method**

```
public static class MQueueUserAPC
{
    public static bool Inject(string dllPath, string processName)
    {
        // Get the pointer to load library

        var loadLibraryPointer = GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle("kernel32.dll"), "LoadLibraryA");

        if (loadLibraryPointer == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            return false;
        }

        // Get the handle of the specified process

        var processId = Process.GetProcessesByName(processName)[0].Id;

        var processHandle = OpenProcess(ProcessPrivileges.AllAccess, false, processId);

        if (processHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            return false;
        }

        // Allocate memory for the dll name

        var dllNameSize = dllPath.Length + 1;

        var dllMemoryPointer = VirtualAllocEx(processHandle, IntPtr.Zero, (uint) dllNameSize, MemoryAllocation.AllAccess, MemoryProtection.PageReadWrite);

        if (dllMemoryPointer == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            return false;
        }

        // Write the dll name into memory

        var dllBytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(dllPath);

        if (!WriteProcessMemory(processHandle, dllMemoryPointer, dllBytes, (uint) dllNameSize, 0))
        {
            return false;
        }

        // Call QueueUserAPC on each thread

        foreach (var thread in Process.GetProcessesByName(processName)[0].Threads.Cast<ProcessThread>())
        {
            var threadId = thread.Id;

            // Get the threads handle

            var threadHandle = OpenThread(ThreadAccess.SetContext, false, (uint) threadId);

            // Add a user-mode APC to the APC queue of the thread

            QueueUserAPC(loadLibraryPointer, threadHandle, dllMemoryPointer);

            // Close the handle to the thread

            CloseHandle(threadHandle);
        }

        // Close the previously opened handle

        CloseHandle(processHandle);

        // Free the previously allocated memory

        VirtualFreeEx(processHandle, dllMemoryPointer, dllNameSize, MemoryAllocation.Release);

        return true;
    }  
}
```

**How I am using it in my Windows Form / Console Application**

```
var injector = new Injector();

if(Injector.QueueUserAPC(dllPath, processName))
{
    MessageBox.Show("No error was raised");
}
```

I guess what I am asking is do Windows Forms have fewer permissions than Console Applications and if so, how could I configure my Windows Form so that I don't run into the problem of the process crashing when trying the use QueueUserAPC.

If you would like to test the library I have it on [Github](https://github.com/Akaion/Simple-Injection) with instructions on how to use it.

Comment: There shouldn't be, unless your antivirus is running your app in a sandbox. You can test out the permissions issue by running your application with elevated privileges. Easiest way is to restart Visual Studio under admin privileges, or you can compile then right click on the .exe and "Run As Administrator".

Comment: Running under administrator yielded the same problem. I guess permissions aren't the issue here. Do you have any ideas as to why it would work in a console application but not a windows form application?

Comment: Stepping into the `QueueUserAPC` call, which line does it break on?

Comment: It doesn't break on anything. True is returned and the MessageBox is displayed, however, 2 - 3 seconds later the process (that is being injected into) crashes. I copied the exact same code into a console app and fresh windows form app and it works fine in the console app but not the windows form app.

Comment: What is the error (in the application error log) that the application is reporting when it crashes?

Comment: You are mixing Ansi and Unicode wrong, use `LoadLibraryW` instead. And you are leaking resources if an error occurs. And you are asking for too many rights from `OpenProcess()`, and no error handling on `OpenThread()`. And you should not call `GetProcessesByName()` multiple times, call it once and cache the result locally. And read the documentation for `QueueUserAPC()`, there is a big warning about queuing functions across process boundaries. And using `QueueUserAPC` to run `LoadLibrary` is not very reliable (most threads do not use Alertable waits), consider `CreateRemoteThread` instead

Comment: @RemyLebeau thanks for the advice on improving the code. I'll definitely make those changes. As for using CreateRemoteThread I have that method in my library already. I'm only using this method as proof of concept.

Comment: @RonBeyer It's reporting the following "Exception code: 0xc0000005" "Faulting module name: ntdll.dll" "Fault offset: 0x00051c0a"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

process is crashing because you call `VirtualFreeEx` for memory, where you store name of dll (`dllMemoryPointer`). when `LoadLibrary` begin use this memory it can be already not valid. *APC* - this is **asynchronous** procedure call, so you can not know ,at point where you call `VirtualFreeEx`, are `LoadLibrary` already executed or in process, or even not begin.

*about the permissions* - of course no. if you have no permissions - you simply fail open process or threads in process. as result nothing will happens. that you got crash in target process, visa versa confirmed that you have permissions.

also need understand that not all threads in process will be in alertable state, after you inject *APC* to it. so possible, despite that *APC* will be successfully queued - it will be never called. inject it to all threads in process, hoping that at least one of them will be in alertable state wrong way. at first may be not, at second - some working threads can be not design for call `LoadLibrary` at all - say thread can have no activation context, not connect to csrss, may be some else. all this also can produce crash or undefined effects. and finally this is simply not efficient.

the injection via `QueueUserAPC` useful in case you create process itself (in suspended state) and inject apc to the initial process thread before resume it. this will be work (how minimum until) because new thread in process begin execute in user mode always from `LdrInitializeThunk` (where he initialize process and/or call load dlls code) and before jump to real entry point always (in all existing windows versions) call `ZwTestAlert`. exactly at this point your *APC* call will be executed. but strictly speaking this is also not 100% correct way, because we use `LoadLibrary[W/A]` as *APC* entry point. but what will be if *APC* exceuted too early, when `kernel32.dll` yet not mapped to process or yet not initialized ? obviously that crash. in clear windows must not be this situation (apc will be called after process fully initialized, all static dll loaded, just before call exe entry point). but possible that some drivers will inject self code to process via *APC* call (say on mapping *kernel32.dll* event ) and force *APC* executing at this point. as result only 100% reliable way here use `ZwQueueApcThread` to shellcode, which will be call only ntdll api, load dll via `LdrLoadDll` and dll itself have static import only from *ntdll.dll*